# How to properly resize storage partition dual-boot Macbook Pro?

Tags: mac, partitioning, gnome, gparted, manjaro

This is a picture of GParted from my dual-boot macOS High Sierra and [Manjaro](https://manjaro.org). I recently decided to create an exFAT storage partition that could be shared between the two, and then later realized I had plenty of free space in my Mac partition to add to the storage partition.

After shrinking the APFS partition in Mac, I have this unallocated space right in the middle. What I want is to use this space to expand the storage partition.

How would I do that given how many partitions they have between them?

[image: GPARTED image]